# Delphi & Active Directory security groups

Tags: delphi, active-directory

Im writing a program for my school in which users have to enter a code given to them by a teacher to access the internet.

My Question is how can i from delphi check if the current user is part of the teacher security group in active directory or not before it runs my code generating program.

Thanks
Erik

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337300/how-do-integrate-delphi-with-active-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answers [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337300/how-do-integrate-delphi-with-active-directory)

Comment: Ive had a look at this but i am struggling on working out how to use the unit there. If i can papulate a stringgrid or listbox with a users groups i can easily work it out from there. Or can i only search for a predefined groupname?

Comment: Using the code example I posed in that thread, just call TADSI.GetUser and inspect the returned Groups value. Or call TADSI.Authenticate(Domain, UserName, Group: string) and pass the name of the Group for "teacher security".

Comment: Thanks for your help. ive manageds to whittle through some of the errors i was getting and im now stuck with undeclaired identifer group & domain. Adsi & ActiveDs_TLB & adshlp have been added to the units. 

label1.Caption := TADSI.Authenticate(Domain, UserName, Group: string) ;

also how do i pass it the group name? do i replace string? 

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, TASDI.Authenticate returns a boolean so assigning that to a Caption property wont work. Secondly, you need to CREATE the TADSI object, assign it to a variable and then call the methods, e.g.
var 
  ActiveDir: TADSI;
  Authenticated: boolean;
begin
  ActiveDir:=TADSI.Create(Self);
  Authenticated:=ActiveDir.Authenticate('DomainName','UserName','GroupName);
  ActiveDir.Free;

Comment: Hi gerard. thanks for your patiance. And thank you verry much. the program is now working perfectally. i had to take out activedir.free as it was spitting out read errors, but now it works perfectally fine. Once again thanks :-)

Comment: How about tagging this post as Answered?

Answer (score 3):

Using winapi functions.

But have a look at Jedi JWSCL, that is an underdivision of Jedi APIlib that are building a security related library for Delphi.

http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/category/downloads/jwscl-downloads/

Comment: Sorry, 
User and Groups Management is currently not supported by JWSCL. However, there are plans and a unit skeleton for this feature. Only missing thing is time or volunteer(s).

Comment: Just finished this article for you: 
http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2010/02/22/jwscl-features-overview/