# Using an Imported TLB - "Types of Actual and Formal Var parameters must be identical" error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, adsi

I am having issues using an imported type library in Delphi 2010 and cannot for the life of me get my head around how to fix it.

`ActiveDs_TLB` defines the following:

```
function SetSearchPreference(var pSearchPrefs: ads_searchpref_info; dwNumPrefs: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
```

I assume then this requires a pointer to an array of ads_searchpref_info, but I can't do the following:

```
SetSearchPreference(@MySearchPref,1);
```

because I then see the dreaded `E2033 Types of Actual and formal var parameters must be identical` error

Further down, `ActiveDs_TLB` defines:

```
    function ExecuteSearch(pszSearchFilter: PWideChar; var pAttributeNames: PWideChar; 
                       dwNumberAttributes: LongWord; out phSearchResult: Pointer):HResult; stdcall;
```

but then when I try to pass a `nil` as the second parameter it complains again.

### Edit 1:

The tlb is from Golez as part of the answer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4184306 - the code above is from his answer - this equates to the issues I've had also getting adsi to work.

I am using W7 64 bit - that shouldn't make a difference as the adsi dll is 32 bit.

### Edit 2:

I mistakenly assumed the issue was with the function due to the error hitting there because I blindly followed the code. After throwing in a few error traps, it seems the object is never created, which of course throws the av when I try to assign a value to it.

Answer assigned as it was the first to point out the obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one takes a parameter of type `ads_searchpref_info`.  This is probably not a pointer.

On the 2nd one, since it's a `var` parameter you can't pass a constant, it must be a variable since it expects to be able to change it / pass information back out.

Comment: If I pass a plain `ads_searchpref_info` then I just get an access violation.

Comment: And for the second, I understand it's a var, but it can be NULL as long as dwNumberAttributes is 0 or FFFFFFFF

Comment: It still must be a variable assigned the value nil since it is a var parameter.  On the first, I can't help you with bugs in their implementation, but that is the type the function signature expects.

Comment: @MarkRobinson: It's asking for a number, so this is probably supposed to be an array, not a pointer to a single item, and the person who translated the header messed up.

Comment: looks the same using the "import component -> type library" functionality within Delphi 2010 :(

Answer (score 3):

If it's defined as a **var** parameter, it means you should only pass a single element, and let Pascal take care of the pointer.  If the original library is expecting an array, because pointers and arrays are interchangeable in C, then your TLB translation was done wrong.