# Get a list of Active Directory Users along with their Full Name and Email

Tags: windows, delphi, active-directory, delphi-2010

I need to retrieve a list of Active Directory users and their attributes using Delphi 2010.

I've seen a few similar questions on SO (e.g. [Delphi - Find primary email address for an Active Directory user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184306/delphi-find-primary-email-address-for-an-active-directory-user)), but they all seem to require the user name before any additional information can be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I discovered [TJvObjectPickerDialog](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvObjectPickerDialog), part of JVCL. It wraps the Windows Select Object dialog and does everything I need with very little coding. Just set the required properties and call execute. The selected user objects are returned along with the attributes that you set in the 'Attributes' property.

Comment: Any chance you could post some code snippets to show others how you did it using TJvObjectPickerDialog rather than leaving them knowing it can be done but not how?

Answer (score 1):

I had written an article for [The Delphi Magazine] way back when..... if you have access to a backlog of those magazines, it's in issue no. 62 (October 2000) - unfortunately, it seems those back issues aren't available for purchase anymore :-(

It's too long of an article and a code sample to post here.... basically it's about wrapping the [`IDirectorySearch` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a nicer Delphi-like shell. You pass in a base container where to search, you define an LDAP filter, and you define a set of attributes you're interested in - then you search and get back basically an enumerator for the results, which you can get one by one.

Comment: Any chance you could post it online somewhere? Just the source code would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your help Marc, but I found another answer before I had much time to look into your code. The article was interesting though.