# How can I authenticate users using their Windows login credentials?

Tags: delphi, authentication, intraweb

How can I let my Intraweb XI application authenticate users using their Windows login credentials?  The application runs as a service on Windows servers.

We need to only allow network users to access some of our Intraweb applications.

Comment: Are the intraweb clients running inside the domain, or also from a remote location?

Comment: Yes. The clients are running inside the domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Delphi, but it sounds like you want Active Directory integration (assuming here that you already have a AD Infrastructure in place that does the authentication, since you say "Windows login credentials").

If that's the case, then perhaps [Deepak Shenoy's white paper on Active Directory Service Interfaces](http://www.agnisoft.com/white_papers/active_directory.asp) or [the Stack Overflow question about integrating Delphi with Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337300/how-do-integrate-delphi-with-active-directory) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Note that OP is asking how to authenticate webusers for intraweb applications. So he's looking for a interweb solution that will authenticate users of the webpage on the domain that the webserver is running on.