# Delphi Datasnap & Active Directory

Tags: delphi, active-directory, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3, datasnap

Hi I am using Delphi XE2 & XE3

Is there any way to get Delphi Datasnap to Logon using credentials from windows Active directory?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938702/how-can-i-authenticate-users-using-their-windows-login-credentials)
or u can check this one [all u need about AD](http://www.agnisoft.com/white_papers/active_directory.asp)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the DCOM datasnap version and not the dbExpress one. DCOM is fully integrated in AD, while dbExpress is not. DCOM automatically uses the process user credentials to authenticate against the remote server (and it's usually the reason if you not configure it properly you get a lot of "Access denied" errors).
dbExpress Datasnap architecture AFAIK lacks the plumbing to allow for such kind of authentication. Remember that using AD authentication doesn't mean to send the server your domain user/password (especially on an unsecure channel, and in clear text!!!! It's dangerous at put your network security at risk!!!), but exchanging a security token. Any technique that makes you transfer user/passwords to the server is flawed and dangerous, and destroys the very foundations of AD security.