# How can I authenticate a Windows domain user in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ldap

I am trying to authenticate windows domain user in Delphi. I used the code below. 
If I use `ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION`, it says

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

If i use ADS_USE_SSL it is saying

> An invalid dn syntax has been specified

```
function TLoginForm.Authenticate( pUser, pPassword,pDomain: WideString): Boolean;
Var
 aUser,Obj : IAdsUser;
 infoback : HRESULT;
begin
 Try       
   CoInitialize(nil);
   infoback := 0;    

   infoback  := ADsOpenObject(Format('LDAP://%s',[pDomain]),Format('%s',[pUser]),pPassword,ADS_USE_SSL,IAds,aUser);
   CoUninitialize;
   Result := true;
   ShowMessage('Success');
     // here retrieve the information needed
 Except
   On E:Exception do
   Begin
      Result := false;
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
      aUser := Nil;
   End;
 End
end;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? My initial suspicion is unicode...

Comment: Also, if this is inside of a VCL form, then there's no need to call `CoInitialize()` because VCL has already done it for you.

Comment: Did you read the *remarks* in ADsOpenObject's documentation?

Comment: Follow the recommendations by Microsoft, see: https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/kb/180548

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do integrate Delphi with Active Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337300/how-do-integrate-delphi-with-active-directory)

Comment: @JerryDodge We are using Delphi XE5.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me as long as I use a Fully Qualified Domain Controller:

```
var
  hr: HResult;
  pObject : IADs;
  Pwd : String;
begin
      Pwd := 'Hello';
      hr := ADsOpenObject('LDAP://'+ FQDC,
                       'Administrator',
                       Pwd,
                       ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
                       IID_IADs,
                       pObject);
      OleCheck(hr);
      pObject := nil;
end;
```

[more on the name and path formats..](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: how did you imported ADsOpenObject?

Comment: @asgar, via EMB Web.Win.AdsTypes

Comment: I am importing like this. Do you think am i doing wrong.
function ADsOpenObject(lpszPathName,lpszUserName,lpszPassword : WideString;
dwReserved : DWORD; const riid:TGUID; out ppObject): HResult; safecall; external 'activeds.dll';

Comment: @asgar, declarations match but see my updated answer with the correct pObject type

Comment: @asgar, I am testing against an Ubuntu Samba DC which is now rated 2008RC2 and am only using the DCs Fully Qualified Name: "LDAP://vmHome.home.local".

Comment: @asgar, which DC version do you use?

Comment: I am not sure what the DC version is, its out of my hands. I only know the FQN and interface is based on Novell Corporate eDirectory. Please let me know what i can try with different versions.